# Displaying image from a database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have heard that is a very bad idea to save images in the database so I decided to save the path of the image. The problem here is that I can t find a way to show the image.
I tried this

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypassword");
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');


if (!$con)
{
    echo "problem with connection" .mysql_error();
}
?>
<?php
mysql_select_db("eshop",$con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products", $con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($row)
 {   
$myimage = '<img src="<?php echo $row[\'image\']; ?>" />';
echo $row['title'] . " " . "<br />" . $myimage . $row['category'];
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 }
 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and  other similar ways with no result.
Anyone has a clue on this?

Comment: Shouldn't `mysql_fetch_array` come *before* you use `$row`?

Comment: ofcorse it should, i cut off some code to save space :)

Comment: Next time, make sure it is in the correct order, because you will get answers like Norse's.

Comment: thank you for mentioning, next time i will be aware of this :)

Comment: You have an endless while loop because $row never changes within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are there php opening and closing tags in there?
You can just do:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products',$con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$myimage = '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';
echo $row['title']. ' ' . '<br/>' . $myimage . $row['category'];
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Please note that mysql_* functions are going to be deprecated in the next version or the one after that. You should use mysqli or PDO instead.
Also if you don't intend to have variables inside other variable definition you should use single quotes because php parses strings inside double quotes. It's a bit faster if you use single quotes when needed.

You can see what I mean about single and double quotes here:
http://codepad.org/UW5DO2fT

Comment: thank you! I know that myswl_* functions are old, but this is for college and professor 's note use this functions :( btw it worked great!!! thank you!

Comment: efxaristw :) eimai entelws asxeth :P

Comment: Τίποτα, αν θες άλλη βοήθεια, βάλε tag "php". Αυτά βλέπω πιο πολύ. Ή μπορείς να στείλεις και mail.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call `$row` before you've even set it or called the mysql array.

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $myimage = '<img src="<?php echo $row[\'image\']; ?>" />'
 echo $row['title'] . " " . "<br />" . $myimage . $row['category'];
```

You also want to escape the single quotes around 'image' or you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: thank you for the escape quotes, i wasn t aware of this... I edit my post and I now show my code. I cut it of to save space and time and not to bother people with extra code!